# Prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty} (\ln x) = \infty$

Tags: analysis, limits, functions

Can someone help me prove that the function $\ln(x)$ diverges to infinity as $x$ approaches infinity. I tried using the definition to show that $\lvert \ln(x) -∞ \rvert < \epsilon $ where $\epsilon > 0$ and there exists a number $N$ which is in the set of natural numbers where $x > N$, proving that it does indeed diverge to infinity but I can't get any further.

Any help is appreaciated.

Comment: $\ln$ is monotonically increasing. So, you only have to show that $\ln$ is not bounded. This follows from $\ln(e^x) = x$.

Comment: Looking at your question history ($5$ closed questions out of your $7$ for a total of $-12$ votes) I don't even know why I bother but anyway, may I point out to you what you already know: This post does not 
match [users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it will attract downvotes and/or be put on hold. For information about writing math on MSE see 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You should look again at the definition of “diverges to infinity”: $\ln(x)-\infty$ means nothing at all.

Comment: @egreg: $\ln(x) - \infty$ means $-\infty$ so long as $x \neq +\infty$.

Comment: @Hurkyl No, not in that context, at least.

Answer (score 5):

I guess you want an analysis using the definition of divergence at infinity.

Let $M > 0$; and note that $\log x > M$ if $x > e^{M}$. 
This shows that for every $M > 0$ there is some $X > 0$ (take $X := e^{M}$, say) such that $x > X$ implies $\log x > M$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

show that if $x > \lceil\exp(M+1) \rceil$, then we must have

$$\ln(x)>M$$

Answer (score 1):

Your error is that you have the wrong definition of limit.

Finite limit (with value $L$):

> $\forall \epsilon > 0 :\; \cdots \implies |f(x) - L| < \epsilon$

Limit is $+\infty$

> $\forall M:\; \cdots \implies f(x) > M$

Limit is $-\infty$

> $\forall M:\;\cdots \implies f(x) < M$

You used the version for finite limits, rather than the version for a limit equal to $+\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

One can use $\ln(x)=\int_1^x\frac{1}{t}dt\,$ (differentiable with $\ln'(x)=\frac{1}{x}$) and L'Hopital's (actually Bernoulli's) rule as follows:

Suppose that $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}\ln(x)=L<\infty$ (as $\ln$ is a strictly increasing function, we only have two options: $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}\ln(x)=\infty$ or $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}\ln(x)=L<\infty$) and define $f(x)=L-\ln(x)$, which satisfies $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=0$. By L'Hopital's rule $$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}xf(x)=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(x)}{\frac{1}{x}}=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{-\frac{1}{x}}{-\frac{1}{x^2}}=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}x=\infty.$$

Hence, using L'Hopital's again $$0=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{xf(x)}{x}=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(x)-1}{1}=-1.$$ Therefore, $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}\ln(x)=\infty.$